# old url not working in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have updates the system on my website and so i want to do some redirects for links to the new pages .

i am trying the following rewriterule ^jor/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=([0-9]*)&Itemid=([0-9]*)$ index.php?page=article&id=$1

but it's not working . just an 'invalid link' .

and how to make it 302 redirect ?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to answer your second question. You do a 302 redirect with `[R=302,L]`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match the query string directly with RewriteRule; it will only match the file path. You need to use `RewriteCond` and `%1` (rather than `$1`)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)&Itemid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^jor/index.php index.php?page=article&id=%1&itemid=%2 [R=302,L]
```

Note a few things:

1) It's assumed that id is followed by itemid which is followed by the end of the string. `itemid=1337&id=42` will not work because the order is swapped.

2) The rule makes no assumptions about the rest of the query string. It could just as well begin with `option=com_radio`.

3) Note the `+` after `[0-9]` which is needed to match more than one character. (`+` means "one or more")